# Shell script exit code and logging

Tags: linux, shell, logs, exit

I have got following simple shell script, in which I am trying to send STDERR & STDOUT to both screen and log it in a file(test.log). Also, while exiting I am trying to exit with appropriate exit codes.

In this code, I would expect it to echo first message (within the block) and exit. But, it is echoing both the statements and always exit with 0.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/ksh

n_exitstatus=0

{
  n_exitstatus=1
  echo "Inside block : $n_exitstatus"
  exit $n_exitstatus
}  2>&1 | tee -a test.log

echo "Before last exit : $n_exitstatus"
exit $n_exitstatus
$ sh test.sh
Inside block : 1
Before last exit : 0
$ echo $?
0
```

How to amend this script to exit just after echo'ing first statement (to be logged in both screen and file) ?

Answer (score 2):

You use the inner code block in a pipe. This forces the shell the run a sub shell. Exit only leaves the function. If you remove the pipe `| tee -a test.log` it should work as you expected.

So the easiest solution would be remove the pipe from the block and put it behind the inner echo command.

You could also create a function using the block as body, execute it and use the return value to decide to exit before going furter in the outside code.

**Edit**
Here's a useful link: http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/ksh-functions.html

Comment: Not the clearest description (specifically `function` isn't helpful or correct here) but correct nonetheless. The issue here is that segments of a pipeline are executed in a sub-shell and so the first `exit` does not propagate to the parent shell.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yep, you are right. I was thinking on the solution to use a function when I gave the explanation. (I'm a man. I am not able to do multiple tasks at a time.) It's executed in a sub shell without spawning a new process. I checked this with `echo $$` inside and outside of the block. Both time the same process id. I'm not sure but, I expect the sub shell to have its own $<vars>.

Comment: `$$` is treated specially by bash in a sub-shell (documented in the section on `$` if you look) you need `$BASHPID` (bash 4.0+) to see the sub-shell pid.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried it. It worked. Lessons learned.

Answer (score 1):

This is closely related to this question: [Is there a way to write a bash function which aborts the whole execution, no matter how it is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9893667/4941495)

Implementing the solution given by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9894126/4941495), we have this:

```
$ cat test.ksh
#!/bin/ksh

trap 'exit $n_exitstatus' TERM

SCRIPT_PID="$$"

n_exitstatus=0

{
    n_exitstatus=1
    echo "Inside block: $n_exitstatus"

    kill -s TERM $SCRIPT_PID

}  2>&1 | tee -a test.log

echo "Before last exit: $n_exitstatus"
exit $n_exitstatus
$ chmod +x test.ksh
$ ./test.ksh
Inside block: 1
$ cat test.log
Inside block: 1
```

The only thing not quite right still is that the exit status of the script is 0, not 1. This is because the exit happens from the outer scope where `$n_exitstatus` is zero.